# tsconfig.json is apparently being ignored?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need help in understanding why my tsconfig.json is being ignored? The tsconfig.json has a target of `es5` and yet I'm still getting this error?

I have directory with the following:

- test.ts
- tsconfig.json

test.ts

```
let passcode = "roscoes"

class Employee {
    private _fullName: String

    get fullName(): String {
        return this._fullName
    }

    set fullName(newName: String) {
        if (passcode && passcode === "roscoes") {
            this._fullName = newName
        } else {
            console.log("Error: Not authorized ")
        }
    }
}
let employee = new Employee()
employee.fullName = "Johnny Appleseed"

if (employee.fullName) {
    console.log(employee.fullName)
}

console.log('testing')
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "files": [
        "./**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

when I run `tsc test.ts` I get:

```
test.ts(6,6): error TS1056: Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and
 higher.
test.ts(10,6): error TS1056: Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 an
d higher.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `tsc filename.ts` to compile specified files, the `tsconfig.json` will be ignored.
Please refer this [issuse](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5497).

Instead of `tsc filename`, you can use `tsc`, this will always get `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: `tsc` will not always get `tsconfig.json`, it doesn't here